# Regex find URL by keyword/string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I need a regex (PHP) to get a full URL that contains a certain string from a block of text which can contain multiple URLs.

E.g.

Regex to search the following text for a URL that contains specialkeyword.

```
<p>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. 
</p>
<a href="http://example.org/specialkeyword/test/testing">url</a>
<a href="http://example.org/notkeyword/test/testing">url</a>
<p>
    It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</p>
<script>
    var Url = 'http://example.org/notkeyword/test/testing';
    var Url2 = 'https://example.org/specialkeyword/test/testing';
</script>
```

URL will always be wrapped in a single or double quote if that helps.

Comment: You need a better description of what the string look likes and are they always in a common format `"http://example.com"` etc...

Comment: @AbraCadaver I have added an example. Is this sufficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **URL** will always be wrapped in a single or double quote if that helps.

If you absolutely need to use a regular expression you can consider the following:

```
preg_match_all('~(?=[\'"]https?.*specialkeyword)[\'"]\K[^\'"]*~', $text, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

**Explanation**:

```
(?=                 # look ahead to see if there is:
  [\'"]             #   any character of: '\'', '"'
  http              #   'http'
  s?                #   's' (optional)
  .*                #   any character except \n (0 or more times)
  specialkeyword    #   'specialkeyword'
)                   # end of look-ahead
[\'"]               # any character of: '\'', '"'
\K                  # '\K' (resets the starting point of the reported match)
[^\'"]*             # any character except: '\'', '"' (0 or more times)
```

[Working Demo](https://eval.in/172763)

Comment: That works great @hwnd. The URL will also always be http or https and absolute, I'm guessing adding this into the regex would be safer as the above could match the specialkeyword anywhere.

Comment: That seems perfect. I'm grateful to you for your help.